# I float on water, but sink on sand

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I float on water, but sink on sand;

I'm neither creature, beast, nor Man.

I'm slip-and-slide-y, smooth and slick,

But watch for snakes: they make me a trick.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be

> Oil

I float on water, but sink on sand;

> Oil floats on water, as we see all too often on seas :( but filters through sand.

I'm neither creature, beast, nor Man.

> self explanatory

I'm slip-and-slide-y, smooth and slick,

> Oil is used to lubricate things

But watch for snakes: they make me a trick.

> 'snake oil' is an expression referring to fake medicine

Comment: Correct!  Nice job, and thanks for solving the new-and-improved version of my first riddle!

Answer (score 1):

Could be -

> ICE

Why ?

> It floats on water , put in sand it melts and sink as water

Comment: Good guess, but nope!  That would not really be sinking in sand :)

Comment: I was thinking the same...

Answer (score 0):

You might be

> alcohol,

or

> any liquid that floats on water!!

Comment: Correct!  I had a different one in mind, but this one certainly works as well, so I've given you the checkmark.  I've also edited your answer to use spoiler tags so no one gets it spoiled by accident.  Thanks for solving my first puzzle! :)

Comment: @MegaWidget ;))

Comment: ...but alcohol does not float (nor sink) on water, it dissolves in it - otherwise, you always stir your wine or beer because all the alcohol is on top.

Comment: Oh.  I took their word that alcohol floated on water.  Sorry @mehrdad-pedramfar, I have to take away the check mark as there is a better answer!